# Create array of hours: 00:00, 01:00, 02:00

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
var hours = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   hours.push(i);
}
```

This creates an array with 0,1,2,3,4..... numbers, but I need: 00:00, 01:00, 02:00.....

Comment: Maybe `hours.push(i + ':00');`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
var hours = [];
for(var i=0; i < 24; i++) {
    hours.push((i < 10 ? "0" : "") + i + ":00");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to parse these strings back to the respective number (ignoring the minutes) use something like this:

```
var hourString = "11:00";
var hourAsNumber = parseInt(hourString.split(":")[0], 10);
```

Comment: can you create or convert the strings to numbers?

Comment: What number would 00:00 be?

Comment: @alex I posted a method to parse the strings back to the respective number

Answer (score 0):

Use text instead.

```
var hours = [];
var text_hour;
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   if (i > 9) {
      text_hour = i+':00';
   } else {
      text_hour = '0'+i+':00';
   }
   hours.push(text_hour);
}
```